# How to prepend string to hashtag(#) in AngularJS urls?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Is it possible to prepend string to the # symbol from angular.js urls?

For example:
suppose I having a site as: http://example.com/  then 
when I click on CSharp page, it redirects to http://example.com/#/csharp 
when I click on AngularJS page, it redirects to http://example.com/#/angularjs

So I want to prepend # with string say “language” such that urls become –
when I click on CSharp page, it redirects to http://example.com/language#/csharp
when I click on AngularJS page, it redirects to http://example.com/language#/angularjs

I have below sample code which gives above output –

```
var angularApp= angular.module('MyApp', []);

angularApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

   $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
        })
        .when('/csharp', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/csharp.html',
        })
        .when('/angularjs', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/angularjs.html',
        });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hashPrefix`.
Example:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('language');
```

More at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: It’s giving output as http://example.com/#language/csharp I am expecting as http://example.com/language#/csharp Please advise.